# 1с битрикс SQL инъекции

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я в 1с битрикс подставляю в массив $arFilter значение на прямую из POST это угрожает SQL инъекцией или битрикс "подстрахует"? Сам когда пишу чистый код, использую PDO и плэйсхолдеры, но битрикс не советует так делать, типа "на уровне ядра битрикс защищает от SQL инъекций". Подключаюсь через CIBlockElement::GetList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подстрахует. Но так делать не рекомендую.

Дело в том, что если в фильтре GetList какие-то элементы неприемлемы, то битрикс не вызовет ошибки, а просто проигнорирует эту часть фильтра. В результате итоговый фильтр, а следом и набор полученных данных будет непредсказуем.

Comment: ну если эту "непредсказуемость" вызовут любопытные руки, но вреда это не принесет, то не страшно) На уровне обычного пользователя пусть работает и ладно. Спасибо, что успокоили!

Comment: хех)), руки. Когда вам надо удалить несколько записей в цикле. И записи предварительно ищутся гетлистом по фильтру. А фильтр из-за одного косяка оказывается пустым. И вместо пары записей удаляется все содержимое инфоблока)))

Comment: не не) К удалению чего либо я отношусь с особой осторожностью и там такого "огорода" городить не буду. Это запрос просто на вывод элемента, в котором я получаю $_POST напрямую.